# Is try/catch without finally bad

Tags: java, try-catch, finally

So I know that a `finally` block of code will execute regardless of an exception, but is it bad to not use it? I've been using just `try/catch` and wanted to know if this was a bad practice. Or does it not really matter?

Comment: What is the use of `finally`?

Comment: Java doc answers your question!

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth the code in the finally block will execute whether you have an exception error thrown or not, if you wrote code after the catch block without using finally, it wouldn't execute if an exception was thrown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer, no. It all depends on what happens in your try block. I would say that most of your try-catches will probably not need finally. Finally is however required when you are opening resources in the try block such as files, streams, network etc that you have to close (whether an exception is thrown or not)

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I was declaring/opening a connection in a try block and wanted to close it in the finally, but the scope of the connection variable wasn't going to let that happen. I figured I could close it in the try also, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: But is your connection variable not declared outside the try block? Declaring and closing the connection variable in the try block is unsafe because if an exception is thrown between the time you initialize the connection and the time you close it in the try, then the connection will stay open! What you need to do is declare the connection variable to be = null before the try block and then initialize it in the try block. At the finally block you have to check whether the variable is null and if not, then close it.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was declaring the connection inside of the try keeping the scope to that block. Instead, I should only initialize in the try and declare beforehand.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't have anything you need to clean up at the end, that's perfectly fine. `finally` blocks are almost *always* about resource cleanup... and there are plenty of times where you want to catch an exception but don't have any resources to clean up.

Having said that, only catch exceptions when you can actually handle them or want to wrap them in a more suitable type. My experience is that catch blocks should be far rarer than try/finally or try-with-resources blocks. If you find yourself catching exceptions in most methods, that probably indicates you're misusing them.

Answer (score 4):

The answers by Subdivision and Jon are great, but I just want to complement them with a clarification about a common misconception of how the `finally` block works, mainly the answer to this common question:

**What is the difference between placing code in the `finally` block vs. leaving it right after the `catch` block?**

**Incorrect Answer:** the code after the `catch` block will not execute in case of an exception, unless you put it in the `finally` block.

If that is incorrect, why do we need `finally`?

Well, first of all, the code after the `catch` block **will** run as long as you handle **all** exceptions appropriately, which means that no exception should escape the `try..catch` unhandled. `finally` on the other hand, will run **almost** always even in the case of an unhandled exception escaping the `try..catch`. I said "almost", because some unhandled exceptions may skip the `finally` block, but that's rare.

Another difference is: if you exit your code in the `try` or `catch` blocks, the code after the `catch` block will **not** run. We may think that this is obvious, but it can be tricky sometimes. Examples: `return`, `break` and `continue` (if your `try` and the code after are in a loop), `throw` (if you use it in the `catch` to re-throw an exception to the caller). `finally` will still execute in all those conditions.

One last thing to consider: The use of `finally` clearly states your intention, so it contributes to a more robust and self-explanatory code. If you handle all the above-mentioned conditions carefully and write code after the `catch` thinking that it is as guaranteed to run as the `finally` block, you will probably be fine.... Well, until another developer needs to modify your code in the future and decides to add a `return` (for instance) in the `try`.

**Conclusions**: If you have code that you need to guarantee its execution after your `try..catch`, it is always recommended to use `finally`.

Comment: Thanks for your input Racil, so even without a finally block your code will execute ALMOST always after catch given exceptions are handled correctly. Finally is a more robust way of handling code after a catch.

Comment: Exactly. You're welcome. Feel free to upvote the answer if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you have code that could generate a mistake, you put this code in a `try/catch`. And when we add `finally` is to run code not dependent on the error captured above.

PS: the lines of code contained in `'finally'` are always executed.